# Understanding how akka references are handled upon upstream failure

Tags: akka

I'm building an application that requires delayed response to a `sender` reference pointing to the upstream sender. For clarity, if actor A sends a message to actor B, then A is the `sender` of B.

Upon A's failure and restart by its supervisor, does the `sender` reference held by B still point to the newly restarted A actor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, after a restart the `ActorRef` points to the new *actor instance* which is considered to belong to the same *actor incarnation* (see [the actor lifecycle section of in the Akka docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#actor-lifecycle)).

The documentation also states this explicitly [here](https://doc.akka.io//docs/akka/current/general/addressing.html#actor-reference-and-path-equality):

> Equality of `ActorRef` match the intention that an `ActorRef` corresponds
> to the target actor incarnation. Two actor references are compared
> equal when they have the same path and point to the same actor
> incarnation. A reference pointing to a terminated actor does not
> compare equal to a reference pointing to another (re-created) actor
> with the same path. Note that a restart of an actor caused by a
> failure still means that it is the same actor incarnation, i.e. a
> restart is not visible for the consumer of the `ActorRef`.

So it makes a differences whether the actor is terminated and another instance is created or it is restarted by the supervisor.

Comment: Thanks @lex82 for the help